# How can I parse csv data from a javascript array of strings for use in d3 graphs

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js, lua

I want to use data in a javascript array of strings to produce a d3 graph, to display a time series of timestamp(t), receive (rx), and transmit (tx) counters.  Each member of the array is a string corresponding to one line of time,rx,tx (yes, with comma separators).  I don't want to use d3.request based methods.  I have already read the file from the server using server-side lua code and placed the data into the page using jslines.push(string).

```
109 // Show results so far
110 for (i=0; i < jslines.length; i++) {
111     console.log(i + ": " + jslines[i]);
112 }
```

The above section gives me confidence data is as I've described.  For now I am just trying to pull out each of the 3 data values from a "line" and then repeat.  I don't care that they'll still be strings at this point.  Numbers later.

My reference for this is: https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/master/README.md#csvParseRows but I'm clearly misunderstanding the work needed.

```
114 var dataArray = d3.csvParseRows(jslines, function(d, i) {
115   return {
116     time: d[0],
117     rx:   d[1],
118     tx:   d[2]
119   };
120 });
```

Would be thankful for (kind) suggestions and/or a working example of using d3 to parse and prep data that d3 is not itself pulling from a remote (or local) file.  Most of the examples I can find are asking d3 to pull the file content across to the client station, I believe.

Thanks ...Alan

Comment: Please share the `jslines` array (not all of it, just some elements is enough). Have in mind that `d3.csvParseRows` will parse a string, not an array. Also, please explain exactly *what* is not working in your code... are you getting `dataArray` the way you want? Or is the issue here how to use `dataArray`?

Comment: Each member of the jslines array contains a string, with content like:  "1234567,100,110", already with whitespace trimmed and a single comma between values. All values should be non-negative. With the code as I originally pasted, dataArray comes out nil.

Comment: So, no line breaks? You cannot use that with `d3.csvParseRows`: how can the function know what row it is dealing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the string, you can just split it like this:

```
var a = "1,2,3"
var b = a.split(",")
console.log(b[1])
```

Specifically, for your example, you can extract the data like this:

```
var data = jslines.map(function(l) {
  data = l.split(",");
  return({time: data[0], rx: data[1], tx: data[2]});
})
```

And then construct your d3 plot based on the resulting array of objects.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I followed your example, except that I changed the variable "data" inside the function to "tempdata" (on both indented lines) to keep it clear that data (now tempdata) inside the function is distinct from data outside it.  Not necessary but helped my understanding.  Thanks!